# How do I change subsequent row values if some condition is met with multiple groups?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID  value   condition
A   0         0
A   3         0
A   0         1
A   7         1
A   5         0
A   5         0
A   5         0
A   7         0
B   6         0
B   2         1
B   7         0
B   10        1
B   0         0
B   6         0
```

I want to change the ID name when the condition is met and change the name of the ID that follows too. The condition can be met multiple times per ID so I'd like to modify it each time.

The result would change the original ID or just add a new column:

```
ID  value   condition   newID
A   0              0    A
A   3              0    A
A   0              1    A1
A   7              1    A1
A   5              0    A2
A   5              0    A2
A   5              0    A2
A   7              0    A2
B   6              0    B
B   2              1    B1
B   7              0    B2
B   10             1    B3
B   0              0    B4
B   6              0    B4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could also do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(newID = cumsum(c(0, (condition != lag(condition))[-1])),
         newID = ifelse(newID != 0, paste0(ID, newID), ID))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
   ID    value condition newID
   <chr> <int>     <int> <chr>
 1 A         0         0 A    
 2 A         3         0 A    
 3 A         0         1 A1   
 4 A         7         1 A1   
 5 A         5         0 A2   
 6 A         5         0 A2   
 7 A         5         0 A2   
 8 A         7         0 A2   
 9 B         6         0 B    
10 B         2         1 B1   
11 B         7         0 B2   
12 B        10         1 B3   
13 B         0         0 B4   
14 B         6         0 B4
```

Answer (score 6):

One option after grouping by 'ID', create the index with `rleid` (from `data.table`) and change it to `paste` the 'ID' based on the condition with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(newID = rleid(condition)-1,
          newID = case_when(newID == 0 ~ first(ID), TRUE ~ paste0(first(ID), newID)))
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#   ID    value condition newID
#   <chr> <int>     <int> <chr>
# 1 A         0         0 A    
# 2 A         3         0 A    
# 3 A         0         1 A1   
# 4 A         7         1 A1   
# 5 A         5         0 A2   
# 6 A         5         0 A2   
# 7 A         5         0 A2   
# 8 A         7         0 A2   
# 9 B         6         0 B    
#10 B         2         1 B1   
#11 B         7         0 B2   
#12 B        10         1 B3   
#13 B         0         0 B4   
#14 B         6         0 B4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
 "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), value = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 
 5L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 0L, 6L), condition = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Same idea as @akrun but using only data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, newID := paste0(ID, gsub('^0$', '', rleid(condition) - 1)), ID]
df
#     ID value condition newID
#  1:  A     0         0     A
#  2:  A     3         0     A
#  3:  A     0         1    A1
#  4:  A     7         1    A1
#  5:  A     5         0    A2
#  6:  A     5         0    A2
#  7:  A     5         0    A2
#  8:  A     7         0    A2
#  9:  B     6         0     B
# 10:  B     2         1    B1
# 11:  B     7         0    B2
# 12:  B    10         1    B3
# 13:  B     0         0    B4
# 14:  B     6         0    B4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create subgroups within each `ID` for each contiguous streak of `condition`.

Unfortunately, the OP has requested to name the subgroups in a special way which makes the solutions overly complicated. By OP's request, the subgroups are to be named, e.g., `A, A1, A2` which means that subgroup numbering and subgroup name is off by one, e.g., the second subgroup is named `A1`, the third one `A2`, etc.

In case a more simplified naming scheme would be acceptable, we can directly benefit from the `prefix` parameter of the `rleid()` function. Then, the first subgroup of group `A` will be named `A1`, the second `A2`, etc.

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(newID = data.table::rleid(condition, prefix = first(ID)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 14 x 4
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>    ID    value condition newID
>    <chr> <int>     <int> <chr>
>  1 A         0         0 A1   
>  2 A         3         0 A1   
>  3 A         0         1 A2   
>  4 A         7         1 A2   
>  5 A         5         0 A3   
>  6 A         5         0 A3   
>  7 A         5         0 A3   
>  8 A         7         0 A3   
>  9 B         6         0 B1   
> 10 B         2         1 B2   
> 11 B         7         0 B3   
> 12 B        10         1 B4   
> 13 B         0         0 B5   
> 14 B         6         0 B5
> ```

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newID := rleid(condition, prefix = ID), ID][]
```

> ```
>     ID value condition newID
>  1:  A     0         0    A1
>  2:  A     3         0    A1
>  3:  A     0         1    A2
>  4:  A     7         1    A2
>  5:  A     5         0    A3
>  6:  A     5         0    A3
>  7:  A     5         0    A3
>  8:  A     7         0    A3
>  9:  B     6         0    B1
> 10:  B     2         1    B2
> 11:  B     7         0    B3
> 12:  B    10         1    B4
> 13:  B     0         0    B5
> 14:  B     6         0    B5
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread("ID  value   condition
A   0         0
A   3         0
A   0         1
A   7         1
A   5         0
A   5         0
A   5         0
A   7         0
B   6         0
B   2         1
B   7         0
B   10        1
B   0         0
B   6         0")
```